# Alinhar DIV com position Absolute a outro DIV com position FIXED

Tags: html, css

Estou com um pequeno problema aqui.
neste site:
http://www.gncshop.com.ar/portal/company/

Eu preciso alinhar esse image slider a parte superior da tela, que fique por tras do menu principal.

Como podem ver, existe uma barra preta, bem em cima.
Eu coloquei ela com 10px de altura, mas a ideia depois é deixar ela com 0px mesmo (só coloquei assim para ver se ela esta no lugar certo)

O que preciso agora é posicionar o slider colado nessa barra preta. O slider esta setado com o position: absolute.

Como faço isso?

EDIT: Seguem abaixo os códigos:

```css
.upperfixedbanner {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:10px;
background-color:#000000;
}

.upperfixedbanner > .sliderhomepage {
display:block;
  position: absolute;
width:100%;
top: 0px;
margin-top:0px;
left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="upperfixedbanner">
</div>

<div class="sliderhomepage">
<!--SHORTCODE DO SLIDER-->
  </div>
```

Outras informações:
CMS: Wordpress
Utilizando o Wp-Bakery (pois a cliente pediu um site em que ela possa atualizar facilmente depois a lista de produtos e downloads.)

Answer (score 0):

Use o `position: absolute` no slider, e em seguida altere a propriedade `top` (posição do elemento em relação ao topo do documento) de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Percebi que você colocou um `padding` no seu content (div na qual está o seu slider). Neste caso é recomendável que você retire o `padding` deste content, caso contrário nunca irá alcançar o topo da página.

É interessante também remover o `left` que colocou na sua logo e modificar a maneira com que você a montou. Tente deixá-la apenas dentro de uma `div` ao invés de colocá-la no `h1`. Depois modifique os valores de `margin-left` e `margin-top` para colocá-la na posição que te agrada.

Comment: No momento esta assim:

Comment: .upperfixedbanner {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:10px;
background-color:#000000;
}

.upperfixedbanner > .sliderhomepage {
  position: absolute;
width:100%;
top: 0;
}

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse modelo simples que fiz aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/e7mga97m/

Comment: Só precisa trocar a imagem da paisagem pela div com o seu slider.

Comment: Mas essa forma que você usou, funcionaria em um site feito em wordpress? Em que, por exemplo, toda e qualquer informação que eu coloque em uma página ficará dentro do "content" da página, salvo se eu especificar outra localização.

Comment: Sim. Na verdade dificilmente as coisas mudam no Wordpress. A questão é que no Wordpress, ao invés de você colocar tudo dentro de um único arquivo, o seu template PODE ter colocado uma parte do header.php e outra no index.php (single.php, ou page.php). O HTML continua o mesmo.

Comment: O Slider é feito atraves do plugin meta slider (pra facilitar com que a cliente altere as imagens que ela queira expor)

Todo o código HTML esta sendo feito diretamente na página (nesse caso, nas páginas principais de cada idioma)
O CSS é colocado no custom css do tema....

Testei aqui a ideia, e não deu certo.
Existe alguma outra forma será? de fazer o slider ficar alinhado ao topo da página.

Comment: Vish.. Trabalhar com componentes de terceiro é complicado por causa disso. No caso você tem duas alternativas:

1 - Ir direto no código do slider e modificar o CSS. Vai exigir de você a paciência para encontrar o caminho dos arquivos e entender o CSS dele, mas é a forma mais correta de fazer.

2 - Pegar as classes e ids dos elementos que quer modificar, adicionar e modificá-los no seu CSS usando o `important` que vai sobrescrever os estilos adicionados pelo dono do plugin.

Comment: Beleza! Obrigado Matheus! Vou tentar aqui

Answer (score 0):

A div `<header id="header" class="pagewidth">` precisa está com `position: fixed;` e a classe `.metaslider` com `position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 0;`

Tudo irá subir, mas aí se você não quer isso deve-se usar `position: relative; top: -102px; z-index: 0;`